# VPN button stopped working: Network Manager Plugin

Tags: vpn

I have openconnect and its network manager plugin installed. I have connected to VPN before using the slider button for VPN in the network manager. However the slider button to turn the VPN on is not working anymore. When I try and slide the button to the "On" state, it just does not move. On the other hand, the wireless and the Wireless buttons both work. It seems to be some kind of bug with the Network manager openconnect plugin. Has anyone experienced this bug?

How do I start the openconnect dialog (which will let me input the vpn login and password) without the GUI of network manager?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
openconnect --user username --key-password password
```

If this not working read

```
man openconnect
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I switched to Unity and was able to connect to the VPN again. I think its some issue with Gnome 3's recent updates.